# Dart/Flutter inspect Future "stack traces"

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, future

Sometimes I encounter a deadlock, or something that resembles deadlock.  When I debug code in most languages, I'll usually pause the program and inspect the state of all the running threads, to see e.g. what the thread that was SUPPOSED to pick up the phone is doing instead.  (E.g. via the Debugger > Frames panel in Android Studio.)  In Flutter, however, you don't really use threads, you use Futures, and I haven't found a way to get similar information.  I'd like a way to see all living Futures and where they're waiting in the code.  (In addition to the location each Isolate is executing, I guess, and the Futures categorized by Isolate.)  Is there such a thing?  Is such a feature planned?  (It should be, IMO.)